# Refresh JTextArea in method

Tags: java, swing

I have the following problem:
in my JTextArea I inserted a default string, which must be updated with the new wording once the file is uploaded.
I have the problem that a live refresh of JTextArea is not done, but if I log out and log in I will see the changed string.

```
    public void createWindow()
    {
          // some code...

          JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(1,1);
          String all = "Nothing Infractions";
      try {
        all = new Scanner (file).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        textArea =new JTextArea(100,1);
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        textArea =new JTextArea(1,1);
      } 
    JScrollPane scroll = new 
JScrollPane(textArea,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    textArea.setText(all);
    frmUser.getContentPane().add(textArea);
```

Update:

the text area was thought to have been written without infraction, then passed the program going on randomly and assigning it to each user, the problem and that when assigning them all the logged in user does not automatically update that part of text where no infraction was written.

I Use Java 8

Comment: Do not forget to `close` your scanner.

Comment: Why are you creating a text area that is only one character wide? and why throw that away and re-create a text area in the try-block? And why put the text area in a scroll pane, and then re-parent the text area as a child of the content pane, and then doing nothing with the scroll pane?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from which you cut and paste as needed for your question.  The example below is not fundamentally different from your question, but it allows other users on StackOverflow to replicate the problem and pass along suggestions or solutions.

In addition to modifying the question, please indicate which version of Java you are running.

Based on what you have said, you will probably need to implement some type of listener to determine when the contents of the file change -- or does it get created and never changed?

190418 1646Z: Added a refresh button per your last comment.  Let me know if you would prefer the window to update without having to click a button.

```
package javaapplication7;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class FileWatcher extends JFrame {

    static final File WATCH_FILE = new File("c:\\temp\\java7.txt");
    static final String DELIMITER = "\n";
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(20, 20);

    public FileWatcher() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(600, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setTitle("File Watcher");

        frame.add(createPanel());
        frame.pack();
    }

    private JPanel createPanel() {
        // some code...

        JPanel tempPanel = getPanel();

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        tempPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JButton button = new JButton("Refresh");
        button.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                getUpdatedText();
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            }

        });
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        getPanel().add(button, gbc);

        getTextArea().setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 16));
        getTextArea().setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        getTextArea().setLineWrap(true);
        getTextArea().setWrapStyleWord(true);
        getTextArea().setOpaque(true);
        getTextArea().setVisible(true);
        getUpdatedText();

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(getTextArea(), JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scroll.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));
        scroll.setVisible(true);
        //        frmUser.getContentPane().add(textArea);

        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        tempPanel.add(scroll, gbc);

        return tempPanel;
    }

    public void getUpdatedText() {
        String all = new String();
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(WATCH_FILE).useDelimiter(DELIMITER)) {
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                all = all.concat(scanner.next()).concat(DELIMITER);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            // swallow, next line covers it
        }

        if (all.isEmpty()) {
            all = "No Infractions";
        }
        
        getTextArea().setText(all);
        
    }

    public JPanel getPanel() {
        return panel;
    }

    public void setPanel(JPanel panel) {
        this.panel = panel;
    }

    public JTextArea getTextArea() {
        return textArea;
    }

    public void setTextArea(JTextArea textArea) {
        this.textArea = textArea;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileWatcher javaApplication7 = new FileWatcher();
    }
}
```

Comment: try, but not work in live. Equal problem, the file is generated while the program is running

Comment: So a listener will need to be created.  What version of Java?  That definitely makes a difference.

Comment: I would do well to make a button with the refresh function

Answer (score 0):

Use `revalidate()` and `repaint()`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22783653)

Comment: Acknowledged , from later on i will try to be better